# Java: Do I need to change the soap address of the WSDL?

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl

My wsdl is as follows, I use Spring-WS.

For some test purposes I want to run this build also on my localhost.

Do I need to create another build to change another soap address. Or I no need to change it at all, thus it will work fine with some limitations?

```
<wsdl:service name="MyWSService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:MyWSBinding" name="MyWSPort">          
        <soap:address location="https://mywebsite.com/soapws/ws"/>             
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't need to change it for what I've observed. When you try to access this wsdl through browser by suffixing the service url with **?wsdl** (http://host:port/path/service-name?wsdl) you will see that it is populated with the correct url.

This behavior might be implementation specific though. I am using Axis. It is worth to check by accessing it. But it doesn't matter what the wsdl contains as long as you are able to invoke the service.

Comment: @XDeveloper you doens't need to change this at all to invoke it. The purpose is to publish the service invocation url when the wsdl is shared with other party.

Comment: tnx, one last question..I can access my wsdl file by "service-name(dot).wsdl" BUT NOT "?wsdl" does that mean my configuration is wrong?

Comment: @XDeveloper nope the config is all right. different implementations provide different ways. Seems like .wsdl is the way provided by your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

We use SOAP with AXIS2 and I never had to change this setting for testing on Localhost or on an external server

Comment: tnx, I use spring ws so "when" it is needed to change this address? what is the purpose?